# can't connect nox emulator with VS code

Tags: android-emulator, adb

I am trying to connect nox player to my VS code in order to run and debug my flutter app

I opened CMD and navigate to my nox folder and run this command:

```
nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001
```

it was working well untill I closed the emulator and installed android 7 in Nox, and ture it on again, now this command doesn't work, and it gives this error:

```
C:\Program Files\nox\Nox\bin>nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
* daemon started successfully *
cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:62001: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

developers mod is on in the emulator and also the USB debuging.

any help please.

Comment: `nox_adb.exe` uses an outdated adb protocol. Instead of `nox_adb.exe` use `adb.exe` from Andorid SDK platform tools.